# SQL Server - Get comma separated column names which have values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which has multiple columns (example below)

```
|Customer Id| Attr1 | Attr2 | Attr3 | Attr4 | Attr5 | Attr6 |
|1          | 1     | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 1     |
|2          | 1     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     |
|3          | 0     | 1     | 0     | 1     | 1     | 0     |
```

I want to fetch all customers and the attribute against which that customer has any value.

```
|Customer Id| Vals                |
|1          | Attr1, Attr4, Attr6 |
|2          | Attr1, Attr3        |
|3          | Attr2, Attr4, Attr5 |
```

Note: Column names are known and I am not looking for dynamic query. Also query is for SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

One method would be use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and some `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT YT.CustomerID,
       CONCAT_WS(',',
                 CASE Attr1 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr1' END,
                 CASE Attr2 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr2' END,
                 CASE Attr3 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr3' END,
                 CASE Attr4 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr4' END,
                 CASE Attr5 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr5' END,
                 CASE Attr6 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr6' END) AS Vals
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

---

Seems the OP is not using a recent version of SQL Server, therefore they will need to use a much older method with `STUFF`:

```sql
SELECT YT.CustomerID,
       STUFF(CONCAT(',' + CASE Attr1 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr1' END,
                    ',' + CASE Attr2 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr2' END,
                    ',' + CASE Attr3 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr3' END,
                    ',' + CASE Attr4 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr4' END,
                    ',' + CASE Attr5 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr5' END,
                    ',' + CASE Attr6 WHEN 1 THEN 'Attr6' END),1,1,'') AS Vals
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning it initially but I need it for SQL Server 2012

Comment: Why including the version is important, @Ankit. You'll need to therefore use `STUFF` and `CONCAT`.

Comment: This will give me extra comma like "Attr1,,Attr4"

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select YT.CustomerId,
       stuff( (case when attr1 = 1 then ', Attr1' else '' end) +
              (case when attr1 = 2 then ', Attr2' else '' end) +
              (case when attr1 = 3 then ', Attr3' else '' end) +
              (case when attr1 = 4 then ', Attr4' else '' end) +
              (case when attr1 = 5 then ', Attr5' else '' end) +
              (case when attr1 = 6 then ', Attr6' else '' end),
              1, 2, ''
             )
from t;
```

More recent versions of SQL Server support `concat_ws()`, which is handy in this situation.